# yii.validation is not defined error in yii2

Tags: yii2

[image]

I am opening a ActiveForm in modal window in yii2.
This error comes when I am opening a ActiveForm in Modal window . my index.php is

```
<?php

use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\bootstrap\Modal;

$this->title = 'Roles';
$this->params['breadcrumbs'][] = $this->title;
?>
<div class="role-index">

    <h1><?= Html::encode($this->title) ?></h1>

    <p>
        <?= Html::a('Create Role', '#', [
            'class' => 'btn btn-success',
            'id' => 'create-role-model',
            'data-toggle' => 'modal',
            'data-target' => '#activity-create-modal',
        ]) ?>
    </p>

</div>
<?php

Modal::begin([
    'id' => 'activity-create-modal',
    'header' => '<h2>Hello world</h2>',
    'footer' => Html::button('Close', ['class' => 'btn btn-default', 'data-dismiss' => 'modal'])
        . PHP_EOL . Html::button('Add', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary btn-modal-save']),
]);

$model= new \frontend\models\Role();
echo $this->renderAjax('_form',['model' => $model]);

Modal::end();

?>
```

and my _form.php is

```
<?php

use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\bootstrap\ActiveForm;

/* @var $this yii\web\View */
/* @var $model frontend\models\Role */
/* @var $form yii\widgets\ActiveForm */
?>


    <?php $form = ActiveForm::begin([
        'id' => 'create-ro',
        'enableClientValidation' => true,
    ]); ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'id')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'created_on')->textInput() ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'updated_on')->textInput() ?>

    <div class="form-group">
        <?= Html::submitButton($model->isNewRecord ? 'Create' : 'Update', ['class' => $model->isNewRecord ? 'btn btn-success' : 'btn btn-primary']) ?>
    </div>

    <?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
```

However when I place ActiveForm without render in index.php Yii Validation is working.Am I doing it an wrong manner . What have to be done so that modal validation start

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's `echo $this->render('_form',['model' => $model]);` you need, not `$this->renderAjax()`.

The latter actually terminates the entire page and returns it without a layout around it (so including any javascript includes and so on).

Since you are still in another view that is definitely not what you need. So just use `render()`. It's a bit confusing because `Controller::render()` actually does close the page (and also adds javascripts), but in case of the `View` (Which `$this` is in that context) it does what `renderPartial` does for the controller.